# Window autofocus using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-window

Is it possible to transfer focus to a window automatically when you mouse over it using javascript?

I have a web based application that uses multiple windows so that users can rearrange the interface how they want, but at the moment they must click on a window to transfer focus before they can use it. So to make things a little easier for my users I would like to make it so that focus is automatically transferred to a window when the mouse moves over it.

I have tried using javascript's mouseover() function and jquery's mouseEnter() functions and I get some whirred behaviour where it will fire a hover event on an object at the edge of the window, but it does not focus the window properly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is impossible, it would be a potential security vulnerability if a webpage could arbitrarily take the focus or capture events while not active, especially if it did so while you were entering a password.

Comment: As long as a window can only take focus from another window if it is from the same url then it would only be vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks which one has to protect against anyway. @AlexanderO'Mara

Comment: Fair enough. The use cases seem fairly limited though, so I doubt that any browsers will implement such functionality any time soon.